# Qt. Automatically adding version for application

Tags: qt, qmake

In a `.pro` file, I can set version of application such:

```
VERSION = <some version>
```

Is there a way of doing this automatically (e.g. getting the value from Mercurial)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can get the version from a shell command, you can assign it to the variable with the `$$system` qmake function.

So, for mercurial, you could try:

```
# if the version tag is <major version>.<minor version> 
VERSION = $$system(hg parents --template '{latesttag}.{latesttagdistance}')
# or if you fill all 3 positions manually: <major>.<minor>.<patchset>
VERSION = $$system(hg parents --template '{latesttag}')
```

Or if you are using the local revision number as the version:

```
VERSION = $$system(hg parents --template '{rev}')
```

which will only print that number without the uncommitted change indicator ('+').

Comment: Thanks. But exist more easy solution. You can use $$system($$(PWD)/hg id -n). In this case will return version number of repository. But the problem is that the mercurial can return the number with the symbol "+". This is an invalid character in the version number.

Comment: @Milovidov You can get rid of '+' with the help of `replace()`: `VERSION = $$replace(VERSION, "+", "")`

Comment: @Milovidov You can use a template too for only returning the number part (I edited the answer).

Comment: Worked for me a long time until I have installed VS2012. Then it started to fail with COFF-error as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139685/qt-after-installation-of-vs2012-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff Maybe someone has an idea.