# QtCreator: Mercurial version $$system(hg..) without full path?

Tags: qt, mercurial, qt-creator

Qt Creator 2.5.2 on Win 7: I am using this approach ( [Qt. Automatically adding version for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550071/qt-automatically-adding-version-for-application) ) to add a VERSION number for my source code in Qt Creator.

However, since my Mercurial is installed in `C:\TortoiseHg\hg` , I have to specify

```
VERSION = $$system(C:\TortoiseHg\hg parents --template '{latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}')
```

This full path is not very nice, since others might have installed in different places. The location is correctly set under Qt Creator Tools -> Options -> Version Control -> Mercurial.

Is there a chance (variable) reflecting this setting, or another workaround? Guess in order to use `VERSION = $$system(hg parents --template '{latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}')`  I have to globally add `C:\TortoiseHg\` to `PATH` - which I'd like to avoid for some reasons.

So what is the best way getting rid of the absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pro` file is not only a QtCreator project, but qmake project file - qmake may not know what you specify in QtCreator settings. If you don't want to add path to `hg.exe` to `PATH`, you may want to create separate environment variable an try to use it in `$$system`.